# How do I apply html to a specific screen size in Wordpress?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I noticed my WordPress website built with Elementor looks too zoomed in on the Chromebook.
I was able to fix it using the following code:

```
html {
    zoom: 0.67;
    -moz-transform: scale(0.67);
    -moz-transform-origin: 0 0;
}
```

However, I do not want this code to apply to all screen sizes/resolutions.
What can I do to make the code apply for screens less than or equal to 1366x768?

Answer (score 0):

Use media query. Exemplifying:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    html {
        zoom: 0.67;
        -moz-transform: scale(0.67);
        -moz-transform-origin: 0 0;
    }
}
```

In the example, the code would only apply to devices with a resolution up to 600px.

The documentation to use can be found here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries